# Delete elements attribute-values in XML (WSDL) file?

Tags: xml, xslt, wsdl, mule

I want to in my XML (WSDL) file , Remove some of the elements.

This is my WSDL file:

```
      <wsdl:types>
        ...
      </wsdl:types>

      <wsdl:message>
        ...
      </wsdl:message>

      <wsdl:portType name="countrySoap">
         <wsdl:operation name="GetCountryByCountryCode">
             <wsdl:documentation>Get country name by country code</wsdl:documentation>
             <wsdl:input message="tns:GetCountryByCountryCodeSoapIn" />
             <wsdl:output message="tns:GetCountryByCountryCodeSoapOut" />
         </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetISD">
            <wsdl:documentation>Get International Dialing Code </wsdl:documentation>
            <wsdl:input message="tns:GetISDSoapIn" />
            <wsdl:output message="tns:GetISDSoapOut" />
        </wsdl:operation>
        ...
      </wsdl:portType>

  ....
```

Now I want to delete  `<wsdl:operation name="GetISD">` with all of the elements that it has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="wsdl:operation[@name = 'GetISD']" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Used here:

- [Identity template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform)
- Selective empty template to omit a node from the output.

Comment: Please remember to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) that worked for you.  Thanks!